# Is os.File suitable for http.Request.Body when uploading a file using http.Client.Do()?

Tags: go

```golang
// Body is the request's body.
//
// For client requests, a nil body means the request has no
// body, such as a GET request. The HTTP Client's Transport
// is responsible for calling the Close method.
//
// For server requests, the Request Body is always non-nil
// but will return EOF immediately when no body is present.
// The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP
// Handler does not need to.
//
// Body must allow Read to be called concurrently with Close.
// In particular, calling Close should unblock a Read waiting
// for input.
Body io.ReadCloser
```

According to the document of `http.Request`, the `Body` **must allow Read to be called concurrently with Close. In particular, calling Close should unblock a Read waiting for input.**

I would like to use the return value of `os.Open()` directly as the `Body` of a `http.Request` like this:

```golang
file, _ := os.Open("example.md")
http.DefaultClient.Do(&http.Request{
   Body: file,
})
```

Is that appropriate? Does `os.File` meet the requirement "**must allow Read to be called concurrently with Close. In particular, calling Close should unblock a Read waiting for input**"?

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out!

Comment: That's probably a good question for the mailing list rather than StackOverflow. Calling `Close` on a file will _usually_ unblock a blocked `Read`, however that is not the case on a POSIX system if the calls end up coming from different threads. In most cases though, your `os.File` is a regular file in the local filesystem which isn't going to block indefinitely.

Comment: @JimB Thank you nice guy. I've googled a lot before and there are indeed some issues on GitHub those metion if `os.File.Close` is called cocurrently with blocked `os.File.Read`, then `os.File.Read` will wrongly get stuck in endless waiting. That's what I'm worried about. I really don't want to dig into the complex details of `os.File` and I just wonder if `os.File` can be used as `http.Request.Body` directly. Anyway, thank you for your timely reply! I've posted a copy of this question on golang-nuts :)

Comment: Like I said, a normal file on the file system is not going to block under normal circumstances, so in practice it’s fine. An `*os.File` _in general_ cannot work, for example you wouldn’t be able to unblock the request using stdin.